# Which database should i use with C++?

Tags: database, c++

I am looking for a database with a modern C++ API with JSON-support and it should work on Windows/Linux/MacOS/Android/iOS. I thought of SQLite but I don't know if this is the best choice for this.

Parallel Access should be possible. With SQLite I tought I could implement this with multithreading and mutual exclusions. But I think that is not the best way.

The goal is a database for cooking recipes. Many users should be able to access it at the same time. The Licenses should be GPL oder LGPL. What are your experiences?

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is meant to be single user so it is not a choice.

The traditional way is to run one of the SQL programs, say MariaDb (which is the  truly free version of MySQL) or PostGreSQL.

I would however believe that you might want to look into a No-SQL document database, perhaps CouchBase.